# Runtime 9 error in VBA

Tags: vba, runtime

I wrote the following line of code to find the last row in Column C in my workbook:

```
lastRow1 = Workbooks("ExcelBook").Worksheets("Prices").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

When I run my macro on my own computer (Excel 2010, Windows 8) it works fine. However, I sent it to a client of mine (Excel 2007, Windows 7) and he gets a "runtime error 9 - subscript out of range"

The same thing also happens if I run the macro on Excel for Mac... Could someone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue, macros not working on certain computers - it could need the full workbook name with the extension.  Try

```
lastRow1 = Workbooks("ExcelBook.xlsx").Worksheets("Prices").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with

```
dstring = Workbooks("name").Worksheets("name2").Range("name3")
```

and the issue was solved by adding the extension

```
dstring = Workbooks("name.xlsm").Worksheets("name2").Range("name3")
```